# Visual Studio 2012: Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Thread was being aborted

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms

I have an ASP.NET webforms project that works fine on IIS7.5 (on the web server) and fine on a Windows 7 PC w/Visual Studio 2012 installed on it (to test). On my Windows 8.1 machine w/VS2012, when running the website in debug or release mode, I get the error after clicking a particular button on a particular page (only on that one page):

> Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Thread was being aborted.

The code, including `web.config`, is 100% identical (except for the connection string on the webserver).

I've uninstalled IISExpress (on the Win8.1 PC) and renamed it's folder in the use documents so the settings would not be used again when reinstalling. I also renamed the inetpub on the root drive and in the `Windows/System32` folder (to `inetpub_`). Then I reinstalled IISExpress.  None of this worked to prevent this error on the Win8.1 machine. Another note: the app was working fine before a few days ago.

I'm stumped here. 
Is there another setting (in a config file) hidden elsewhere on the machine that needs changing/deleting to truly and completely clear the offending setting in IISExpress?

The following web.config works on the other machines including the web server (running IIS 7.5), but maybe this is a clue.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <priority value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
    </root>
    <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Bvc5Database" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="appId" value="151951048205184"/>
    <add key="appSecret" value="7129c5fe9c66a3d155e0e2fd6cf02a26"/>
    <add key="appName" value="website"/>
    <add key="appUrl" value="//www.xxxxxxxx.com/"/>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.5"/>

    <compilation debug="true" strict="true" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="Accessibility, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages theme="StoreWideSettings" maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" renderAllHiddenFieldsAtTopOfForm="true" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <namespaces>
        <clear/>
        <add namespace="System"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized"/>
        <add namespace="System.Configuration"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Caching"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Security"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Profile"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add namespace="BVSoftware.Bvc5.Core.Controls" tagPrefix="bvc5" assembly="BVSoftware.Bvc5.Core"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <authentication mode="Forms"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="default.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="default404.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
    <httpModules>
      <add type="BVSoftware.Bvc5.Core.Utilities.LoginPersister, BVSoftware.Bvc5.Core" name="LoginPersister"/>
      <add type="BVSoftware.Bvc5.Core.Utilities.UrlRewriter, BVSoftware.Bvc5.Core" name="UrlRewriter"/>
      <add name="OboutUploadModule" type="OboutInc.FileUpload.UploadProgressModule, obout_FileUpload, Version=1.10.806.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8b4009f4d53d5e5"/>
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="OboutInc.UploadProgressHandler.aspx" type="OboutInc.FileUpload.UploadProgressHandler, obout_FileUpload, Version=1.10.806.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8b4009f4d53d5e5"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <webServices>
      <soapExtensionImporterTypes/>
    </webServices>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="LoginPersister" type="BVSoftware.Bvc5.Core.Utilities.LoginPersister, BVSoftware.Bvc5.Core" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="BVSoftware.Bvc5.Core.Utilities.UrlRewriter, BVSoftware.Bvc5.Core" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <!-- end of addition 10/14/2010-->
    <handlers>
      <add verb="*" path="OboutInc.UploadProgressHandler.aspx" name="UploadProgressHandler" type="OboutInc.FileUpload.UploadProgressHandler, obout_FileUpload, Version=1.10.806.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8b4009f4d53d5e5"/>
    </handlers>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="default.aspx"/>
        <add value="Default.htm"/>
        <add value="Default.asp"/>
        <add value="index.htm"/>
        <add value="index.html"/>
        <add value="iisstart.htm"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The offending code:

```
Protected Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    If Page.IsValid Then
        Dim Basket As Orders.Order = SessionManager.CurrentShoppingCart()

        Basket.SetShippingAddress(StoreAddressEditorShipping.GetAsAddress())
        If SameAsShippingCheckBox.Checked Then
            Basket.BillingAddress = StoreAddressEditorShipping.GetAsAddress()
        Else
            Basket.BillingAddress = StoreAddressEditorBilling.GetAsAddress()
        End If



        If Basket.ShippingAddress.IsValid Then
            If Basket.BillingAddress.IsValid Then
                If SessionManager.IsUserAuthenticated Then
                    Dim user As Membership.UserAccount = Membership.UserAccount.FindByBvin(SessionManager.GetCurrentUserId)
                    If user.Bvin <> String.Empty Then
                        user.CheckIfNewAddressAndAdd(Basket.BillingAddress)
                        user.CheckIfNewAddressAndAdd(Basket.ShippingAddress)
                    End If
                End If
                Basket.UserEmail = EmailAddressEntry1.GetUserEmail
                If Orders.Order.Update(Basket) Then
                    Response.Redirect("~/checkout/Step2.aspx")
                Else
                    MessageBox1.ShowError("Error Updating Shopping Cart, Please Try Again.")
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox1.ShowError("Billing Address Is Invalid")
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox1.ShowError("Shipping Address Is Invalid")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Right after it updates the order, a response.redirect is being called (this is where the page will not redirect and the Firefox web console on the javascript tab shows the error).  I can't step into any more code at that point (it's all the ASP.Net processor from there).
Like i mentioned before, this code has no problems on any other machine except my main one (Win8.1 Pro).

The error points to a script resource, so i clicked on that to see if there were more offending bits (some cut an paste showing the code `w/excess` code removed:

```
// Name:        MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.debug.js
// Assembly:    AjaxControlToolkit
// Version:     3.5.7.429
// FileVersion: 3.5.7.0429
// (c) 2010 CodePlex Foundation
(function() {

function execute() {

... code blocks ...

$type.prototype = {
    get_postBackElement: function BeginRequestEventArgs$get_postBackElement() {
        /// <value domElement="true" mayBeNull="true" locid="P:J#Sys.WebForms.BeginRequestEventArgs.postBackElement"></value>
        if (arguments.length !== 0) throw Error.parameterCount();
        return this._postBackElement;
    },

    ... code blocks ...
}


... code blocks ...
```

at the

```
return this._postBackElement;
```

part

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled VS2012, IIS Express, every config file (deleted iNetpub), then cleaned up the remnants in the registry and  temp files.
After that, reinstalled VS2012 & all the patches.
This did the trick.